# Misunderstanding of scala 'match' compile rules

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, match

I must have some basic misunderstanding of the Scala 'match' semantics or the compiler logic.  This code:

```
val stageStart:Int = 0
val stageShutDown:Int = Int.MaxValue
val stageErrorReport:Int = Int.MinValue

def stageString(stage:Int):String = stage match {
  case stageStart       => "Start"
  case stageShutDown    => "End"
  case stageErrorReport => "Error"
  case _                => "Step " + String.valueOf(stage)
}
```

results in "Unreachable Code" errors on the last 3 'case' statements?  If instead of the names you substitute the actual values (0, Int.MaxValue, Int.MinValue) it compiles -- but now I've hard-coded values that should be referenced by their names (for all the usual reasons).  Since a 'val' can never change, shouldn't the first version also work?

Comment: btw intellij highlights this as warning http://gyazo.com/147de35d25071dafa8de1290b5d23e26

Comment: A warning would be greatly appreciated!  Eclipse raised no warning.  Checked the various properties of the compiler to see if I could turn on a warning for such cases, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 9):

There is a subtle yet important feature: If the identifier in `case` rules start with a lower-case letter, they're always treated as **variables**. So the first `case` matches always (storing `stage` into variable `stageStart`) and the rest 3 are unreachable. You need to define the constants with upper case letters as

```
val StageStart:Int = 0
val StageShutDown:Int = Int.MaxValue
val StageErrorReport:Int = Int.MinValue

def stageString(stage:Int):String = stage match {
  case StageStart       => "Start"
  case StageShutDown    => "End"
  case StageErrorReport => "Error"
  case _                => "Step " + String.valueOf(stage)
}
```

Then they won't be treated as variables but as constants to pattern-match on.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752606/1333025) for [Naming convention for Scala constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9745488/1333025)

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that when you use a variable that starts with a lowercase character, the pattern matcher thinks that you are trying to **assign** to that variable.  So you get this behavior:

```
val stageStart = 0
val stage = 5
def stageString(stage: Int) = stage match {
  case stageStart => println(startStage)  // prints "5"
}
```

Of course, a pattern that is simply an assignable variable will match *anything*, so any subsequent `case` will be unreachable.

To solve this, you need to use a "stable identifier".  This can be done by putting the lowercased variable in backticks:

```
val stageStart = 0
def stageString(stage: Int) = stage match {
  case `stageStart` => "Start"
}
```

or renaming the variable so that it starts with an uppercase character:

```
val StageStart = 0
def stageString(stage: Int) = stage match {
  case StageStart => "Start"
}
```

Also: `String.valueOf(stage)` should be rewritten as `stage.toString`.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the insight -- would have never guessed that.

Comment: But that brings up a more serious issue.  Are you implying in the first example that a variable that was declared as a **val** can actually be **re-assigned** a different value by this match statement?  That seems really scary!  Or is the **case stageStart** actually considered to be a temporary variable -- which is scary in a different way.

Comment: A little research to answer my own question.  The **case stageStart** is actually introducing a new **stageStart** variable that shadows the original.  No warning issued by the Eclipse/Scala environment.  Still consider this very scary -- read the book twice cover to cover, and many other sections multiple times, and the one about uppercase vs lowercase variable names went right by me.  Could also see as a major problem for new Scala people, or anyone trying to migrate a bunch of legacy Java over to Scala.

Comment: In my opinion, one of the best syntactic features of Scala is the **override** modifier.  Makes it impossible to accidentally override a method in a base class, or think that you are overriding a method but mistype the name and wind up not overriding anything.  Yet now we can accidentally shadow a variable with no warning (at least in Eclipse).  I'd vote for requiring the **override** modifier in this case also, to prevent the same type of errors.

Comment: Yep, it introduces a new variable with the same name but in a lower scope, thus shadowing the existing variable.  But shadowing isn't limited to `match` statements.  For example, `val x = 1; { val x = "a"; { val x = 'A; println(x) }; println(x) }; println(x)` is totally valid in Scala.

Comment: Yes, agree that it is perfectly valid in Scala -- just in my opinion this is not a good thing.  I've written an awful lot of code and can't remember any case where I really wanted to re-declare and shadow a variable within a lower scope.  Believe that it opens the door for nasty bugs, and really sets a trap for anyone maintaining the code a year later.  Can anyone come up with a good use-case where shadowing a variable is necessry/desirable?