# Multiple constants assignment in Scala

Tags: scala, variable-assignment

Any idea why I can assign multiple variables using a tuple, but not multiple constants?

```
scala> val (myVar1, myVar2) = (1, 2)
myVar1: Int = 1
myVar2: Int = 2

scala> val (MyConst1, MyConst2) = (1, 2)
<console>:7: error: not found: value MyConst1
       val (MyConst1, MyConst2) = (1, 2)
            ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value MyConst2
       val (MyConst1, MyConst2) = (1, 2)
                      ^
```

I thought actually it is just a matter of naming convention, but this seems like Scala treats identifiers with upper/lower first letter differently.

Comment: This is an example of pattern matching on the "left side of a value definition" and as stated in this answer "identifiers starting with upper case are treated as constants in pattern matching": [naming convention for scala constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745488/naming-convention-for-scala-constants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Samar suggests, in his comment, since you are declaring multiple variables, pattern matching is involved and those Uppercase identifiers are actually treated as Classes which, as your REPL errors suggest, cannot be found.

```
scala> var (Const1, Const2) = (1, 2)
<console>:7: error: not found: value Const1    // <- Const1 class not found
       var (Const1, Const2) = (1, 2)
            ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value Const2   // <- Const2 class not found
       var (Const1, Const2) = (1, 2)    
                    ^

scala> var (const1, const2) = (1, 2)   // <- const1, const2 not treated as classes in this case
const1: Int = 1
const2: Int = 2
```

Comment: Not necessary classes, constants work too. They are simply not treated as variables to bind.  `val One = 1; 1 match { case One => true; case _ => false }`

Answer (score 1):

[Pattern matching section](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html) mentions `varid` (look at e.g. `Simple Pattern`). Now in the [syntax summary](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html) `varid` is defined as

```
lower            ::=  ‘a’ | … | ‘z’ // and Unicode category Ll
...
varid            ::=  lower idrest
```